# Typescript: Passing a function as argument returns window object instead of constructor object

Tags: javascript, typescript, arguments

I'm pretty new to typescript, so I have this function which calls another function inside Class constructor, but when calling `this` inside sayHelloAgain() returns the window object

in `Greeter.init()` im calling `this.sayHello("message string", parameterCallback)`

```
class Greeter {
    init() { 
        this.sayHello("hello", this.sayHelloAgain);
    }
    sayHello(msg, callbackFunction) {
        // Return Greeter object
        console.log(this);
        callbackFunction(msg);
    }
    sayHelloAgain(msg) {
        // Returns Window object instead of Greeter
        console.log(this)
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use the fat arrow notation `sayHello = () => { }` as you wont loose your `this` context if you do so!

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is contextual. Inside `sayHelloAgain` callback, `this` keyword no longer represent an instance of your class.

You can avoid that by:

1 - Using `.bind(this)`

```
this.sayHello("hello", this.sayHelloAgain.bind(this));
```

2 - OR creating another function that calls your callback:

```
this.sayHello("hello", (msg) => this.sayHelloAgain(msg));
```

3 - OR using arrow function in your callback

```
this.sayHello("hello", this.sayHelloAgain);
sayHelloAgain = (msg) => { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This fixed it